# Как сделать закрытия при повторном клике?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день , есть такой код. Открывается попап при клике, закрывается если кликаю на другой элемент либо за его пределы. Как сделать что бы при повторном клике он закрывался

```js
$(function() {
  $('.find-category__item').on('click', function() {
    var to_close = $(this).children('.find-category__dropdown');
    to_close.toggleClass('hidden');

    $(document).mouseup(function(e) { // событие клика по веб-документу
      $('.find-category__dropdown').addClass('hidden');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
}

.find-category__item {
  width: 23%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #c1c1c1;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.find-category__item:nth-child(3n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="find-category__item">
  <div class="find-category__dropdown hidden">
    img/nomer_1</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="find-category__item">
  <div class="find-category__dropdown hidden">
    <div>nomer_2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="find-category__item">
  <div class="find-category__dropdown hidden">
    <div>nomer_3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: в приведенном примере он и закрывается при повторном клике, что же не так ?

Comment: Нажмите именно на серый кружок,( по непонятным причинам при открытие у него выдается margin) . Если нажать на открытый синий background( а это именно и есть элемент) то он не закрывается

Comment: то-есть надо закрывать не при повторном, а при нажатии на сам елемент ?

Comment: Смотри, пожалуйста. пример. Кликаешь на серую точку, появляего его dropdown. При еще одном нажатии НА НЕГО, он не закрывается, а надо что бы закрывался.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант, это поймать клик по открывшемуся блоку и закрыть его :

```js
$(function() {
  $('.find-category__dropdown').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // останавливаем всплытие
    //иначе событие доберется до родителя и блок снова откроется
    $(this).addClass('hidden');
  });

  $('.find-category__item').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).children('.find-category__dropdown').toggleClass('hidden');
  });

  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    $('.find-category__dropdown').addClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.find-category__item {
  width: 23%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  min-height: 30px;
  background: #c1c1c1;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="find-category__item">
  <div class="find-category__dropdown hidden">
    <div>nomer_1</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="find-category__item">
  <div class="find-category__dropdown hidden">
    <div>nomer_2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="find-category__item">
  <div class="find-category__dropdown hidden">
    <div>nomer_3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```